# Python sqlalchemy encode/decode binary key in MSSQL

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, encode

I have problem with decode/encode binary column in sqlalchemy. I have Database in MSSQL where primary keys in tables are Binary.

```
class Kated(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'T$KATED'
nrec = db.Column('F$nrec', db.Binary(8), primary_key=True)
abbr = db.Column('F$abbr', db.String(100), nullable=False)
name = db.Column('F$name', db.String(300), nullable=False)
  
def __repr__(self):
   return '<T$KATED %r>' % self.nrec`
```

I printing values on webpage:

```
   kated = Kated.query.all()
   items = []
   for el in kated:
      items.append({
                'nrec': el.nrec,
                'abbr': el.abbr,
                'name': el.name
            })
   return render_template("posts.html", kated=items)
```

in html

```
   {% for el in kated %}
          <div class ="alert alert-info">
               <h2>{{ el.abbr }}</h2>
               <p>{{ el.name }}</p>
               <p>{{ el.nrec   }}</p>
               <a href="/post_detail?arg1={{el.nrec}}" class="btn btn-warning">Detail</a>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
```

When I printing binary value it's look like
b'\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02'

When I click button "Detail" it generate request

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/post_detail?arg1=b%27\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02%27
```

But when I want find I record by key, Value need to encoding(otherwise it's type error)

```
@app.route('/post_detail', methods=['GET'])
def post_detail():
   arg1=request.args.get('arg1')
   nrec1=arg1.encode('utf-8')
   print(arg1)
   print(nrec1)
   print(type(nrec1))
   print(nrec1.decode())


   kated = Kated.query.get(nrec1)
   return render_template("post_detail.html", kated=kated)
```

result:

```
b'\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02'
b"b'\\x80\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x02'"
<class 'bytes'>
b'\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02'
```

Without encode('utf-8') return error,and with encode('utf-8') value is modified.

Whats wrong?

Comment: It looks like `arg1` is the stringified `repr` of a bytes object (the result of `str(b'\xnn\xnn')`.  You could fix this by calling `ast.literal_eval(arg1)`, but it would be better if the client encoded the data properly (urlencoding or base64).

Comment: Can you tell more detailed? I'm a junior in Python. Thank you.

Comment: I tryed to use urlib. Arg1 is looking like binary, but its a str, and i don't no what to do with it.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show how the incoming request is being created please?

Comment: I edited question as you said. Thank you for help!

Comment: ```ast.literal_eval(arg1)``` really helped. But what about ```urlib```? Thanks

Comment: It looks like the data is coming from the browser as a string, so no need to use urllib or base64 - you might use these when programmatically sending binary data over http.  Typing `b\x01\x02\x03...' into a form on a webpage is unusual though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is part of your problem, but have you tried using sqlalchemy's [sql server data types](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#sql-server-data-types)?

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

class Kated(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'T$KATED'
nrec = db.Column('F$nrec', sa.dialects.mssql.BINARY, primary_key=True)
abbr = db.Column('F$abbr', sa.dialects.mssql.STRING(length=100), nullable=False)
name = db.Column('F$name', sa.dialects.mssql.STRING(length=300), nullable=False)
  
def __repr__(self):
   return '<T$KATED %r>' % self.nrec'
```

Comment: Thank you very match, but result is the same

Answer (score 0):

If the server is receiving this request

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/post_detail?arg1=b%27\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02%27
```

then it seems that a human is typing the string

```
"b'\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02'"
```

into a text input in the browser.  If this is true then the simplest way to get the bytes is to call ast.literal_eval on the string.

```
import ast

@app.route('/post_detail', methods=['GET'])
def post_detail():
   arg1 = request.args.get('arg1')
   bytes_ = ast.literal_eval(arg1)
```

Typing the bytes literal into the input seems like a task a human could easily get wrong, and the use of `ast.literal_eval` is safe, but a bit hacky.  It might be better if the user typed in the hex corresponding to the bytes

```
arg1 = request.args.get('arg1')  # '8000000000000002'
bytes_ = bytes.from_hex(arg1)    # b'\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02'
```

They could even add spaces between the bytes' hex:

```
arg1 = request.args.get('arg1')  # '80 00 00 00 00 00 00 02'
bytes_ = bytes.from_hex(arg1)    # b'\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02'
```